# How to remove RSS links in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

Even if RSS is disabled, it looks like the source is still generating these:

```
<link href="x://www.xxx.com/rss/catalog/special/store_id/1/cid/0/" title="Special Products" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml"/>
```

Tried to search for application/rss+xml in the theme files but no avail. Any ideas where do trim / remove this? As google keeps generating hundreds of 404 pages cause the source links to things that do no exist

Removing that from \app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Head.php did nothing either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't update the Magento core files `app/code/core/..`, if you have to do this, rewrite these files in local.
2. `App/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml`

   ```
   <Mage_Rss>
       <active>false</active> // from true to false
       <codePool>core</codePool>
       <depends>
           <Mage_Catalog/>
           <Mage_CatalogInventory/>
           <Mage_Sales/>
           <Mage_SalesRule/>
           <Mage_Wishlist/>
       </depends>
   </Mage_Rss>
   ```
3. Clean the Magento and browser cache, with this logically Magento doesn't generate a **RSS** sources, **BUT** if you added some custom links in your `theme` of some `module`, this doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. You have to check your extensions and your current theme maybe there is this link written in hard in the head for exemple, `app/design/frontend/{yourPackage}/{yourTheme}/template/page/html/head.phtml` or `header.phtml`

Good luck !